# How to build a Vue Axios service to return promise tree

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I know I'm making this harder then it should be.

A vue method

```
methods: {
    userLogin: function()
    {
        var loginJson = []
        loginJson = JSON.stringify(this.login);
        UserService.login(loginJson);
       //Somehow read the promise, then and catch. 
       // like 
       // loginReturn.then(function(response){
       //     console.log(response);
       // })
        //.catch(function(error){
        //    console.log(error);
        //})                 
    }
}
```

Trying to create some service for vue in a js file.

```
var axios = require('axios')
export default { //I don't think this is correct?

    //Set up some build variable    
    login(data){
        let baseUrl = "http://coolwebsite.com/api/user/login";
        return axios.post(baseUrl, data);

          // .then(function (response) {
          //   console.log(response);
          // })
          // .catch(function (error) {
          //   console.log(error);
          // });

    }
}
```

I would like to return the promise back to the function.  Let the login function handle the promise and figure out what needs to happen on the screen.

Comment: I don't understand.  What isn't working?  You are already returning a Promise from the `login()` of the second file to the `userLogin()` of the first file.  You should `.then()` in the first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, it would be:

```
UserService.login(loginJson).then(response => {
   // handle response...
}).catch(error => {
   // handle error...
})
```

You've already setup `login` to return the promise from axios, so just continue the chain.